# Difference between ivars and (global?) variables defined outside the brackets

Tags: objective-c, ivar

What is the difference between

```
@implementation aClass {
   aType *aVariable
}

- (void)aMethod: {
}
```

and

```
@implementation bClass

bType *bVariable

- (void)bMethod: {
}
```

Is `bVariable` global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `bVariable` global?

Yes.

Objective-C is an extension of C and this is a standard C global variable declaration.

You probably should also look up the meanings of `static` and `extern` in relation to global variables in C.

HTH

**Addendum**

> So back to the first question, the difference is that I can't define `bVariable` again in my entire project, while the term `aVariable` can be reused?

Short answer: No, at least not how you've expressed the question.

Long answer: What you have are two *declarations* each of which declare a *variable* and associate a *name* (or *identifier*) - `aVariable`, `bVariable` - with that variable. As well as a *type*, which is part of the declaration, a variable has a *lifetime* - how long the variable exists - and a *scope* - the part of the program in which the variable is accessible. Scopes can nest, and inner scopes can contain declarations which use the same *name*'s as those in outer scopes, which results in *hiding* - the variable in the outer scope cannot be directly accessed via its *name*.

A *global* variable is one whose *lifetime* is the whole execution of the program, however the *scope* in which a global variable is (directly) accessible need *not* be the whole program (c.f. the `static` qualifier in (Objective-)C), and *different* global variables with non-overlapping scopes *can* have the same *name*.

An *instance* variable is one whose *lifetime* is the same as that of its owning *class instance*, and whose *scope* is the members of the class.

There are also *local* variables, whose lifetime and scope is the containing method, function, block etc. that declare them.

The above is just a quick summary, you should look up the meanings of the all *italicised* terms.

Comment: So back to the first question, the difference is that I can't define bVariable again in my entire project, while the term aVariable can be reused?

Comment: @refdev - see addendum in answer